# Enabling icon previews for custom text files

Tags: finder, desktop, markdown

I have files .mdown which I'd like to have icon previews for in the Finder, like normal .txt files would. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible, yes. But depends on which app you want to open them. Do a Get Info (Comm-I) on any one of them, scroll down to Open With, choose your app, and also choose Use this app to open all docs like this one. You can also copy and paste the doc icon from another .md file. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Not just the doc icon, but have live previews (of the contents of the file).

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't really sure what you were asking, and should have passed. You don't mean what shows up in Quicklook, do you? Good luck, anyway.